# amazon-linux2でエラーAH02454やAH01079などが出てhttpdがうまく起動しません

Tags: php, apache, docker, amazon-linux

```
FROM amazonlinux:2

ENV COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER=1
ENV PATH=$PATH:vendor/bin

RUN yum update -y \
    && yum upgrade -y \
    && yum install -y  \
      curl \
      git \
      libxml2 \
      libxml2-devel \
      httpd \
      mysql \
      gcc \
      vim \
      make

RUN amazon-linux-extras install php7.2

RUN yum install -y \
      php-devel \
      php-mbstring \
      php-opcache \
      php-soap \
      php-mysqlnd \
      php-pear

RUN yum clean all

RUN pecl install xdebug

RUN mkdir -p /www
RUN ln -s /www/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx /etc/httpd/conf.d/
RUN ln -s /www/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/config/xdebug.ini /etc/php.d/

EXPOSE 80
CMD ["/usr/sbin/httpd", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

以上のDockerfileを記述し、buildは成功
docker run後 以下のようなエラーが出ます

/var/log/httpd/error_log

```
[suexec:notice] [pid 1] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 1] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[http2:warn] [pid 1] AH10034: The mpm module (prefork.c) is not supported by mod_http2. The mpm determines how things are processed in your server. HTTP/2 has more demands in this regard and the currently selected mpm will just not do. This is an advisory warning. Your server will continue to work, but the HTTP/2 protocol will be inactive.
[http2:warn] [pid 1] AH02951: mod_ssl does not seem to be enabled
[mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1] AH00163: Apache/2.4.33 () configured -- resuming normal operations
[core:notice] [pid 1] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
```

アクセスログ

```
[proxy:error] [pid 7] (2)No such file or directory: AH02454: FCGI: attempt to connect to Unix domain socket /run/php-fpm/www.sock (*) failed
[proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 7] [client 172.17.0.1:34136] AH01079: failed to make connection to backend: httpd-UDS
172.17.0.1 - - [19/Jul/2018:08:59:29 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 503 299
[proxy:error] [pid 6] (2)No such file or directory: AH02454: FCGI: attempt to connect to Unix domain socket /run/php-fpm/www.sock (*) failed
[proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 6] [client 172.17.0.1:34138] AH01079: failed to make connection to backend: httpd-UDS, referer: http://localhost:8890/
```

ブラウザ画面（`http://localhost:8890/`）

```
Service Unavailable
The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.
```

エラーが出てhttpdがうまく動作しません

Comment: httpd に対してどのような設定を行ったか追記していただけますか。

Answer (score 1):

Docker build の前に、まずは設定を確認して、httpd が起動できるようにしましょう。

- mod_http2 を使おうとしているようですが、prefork MPM では利用できません。worker または event を検討ください。
- mod_ssl がインストールされていないようです。
- fcgi で php-fpm に繋ごうとしているようですが、php-fpm プロセスが起動していないか、ソケットのパスが合っていないようです。httpd ならば php-fpm を使わずにモジュールでいいのではないでしょうか？

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。解決しました！

Comment: @清水幸佑 さん、解決お疲れ様でした！ このサイトでは、回答の左側にあるチェックマークを押すことで「回答を承認」することができ、この機能を使うことで回答者に謝意＋解決したことを伝えることができます。是非お願いいたします。また、信用度が貯まると回答に +1 投票をすることもできるようになります。／別件で、解決したことを知らせるには回答ではなくコメントを使って頂けるとありがたいです。今回は私が回答をコメントに変換してしまいましたが、次からはコメント機能をお使いください。その際、単に「ありがとうございます！」だけではなく、具体的にどのアドバイスが効いたのか示して頂けると、後から同じ問題に遭遇した方の助けになります。今回はお疲れ様でした。今後ともどうぞよろしくお願いいたします :)